# ¿Cómo obtener las keys de varios objetos en un array con Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener en un array nuevo `[test, exam]`. Ya intente con un `for in` para que me de el primero (`'test'`) , pero no se como hacer para que me den todos (`[test, exam, etc]`)

```
var myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typeb:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar el metodo nativo de js **Object.values**.

> **Object.values**
> Devuelve un array con los valores correspondientes a las propiedades
> enumerables de un objeto

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values

```js
let myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typea:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}};


console.log(Object.values(myVar));

/*
[
  {
    "typeA": "501",
    "typeB": "502"
  },
  {
    "typea": "aaaa",
    "typeb": "orale"
  }
]
*/
```

Otra solucion:

```
let myVar = { test: { typeA: '501', typeB : '502' } , exam: {typea:'aaaa', typeb:'orale'}};
let resultado = []; 
for(let o in myVar) { 
  resultado.push(myVar[o]) 
}
```

Comment: hola y con for como seria ?

Comment: Quieres obtener el mismo resultado que Object.values con un for?

Comment: Puedes hacer lo siguiente con un for in
let resultado = []; 
for(let o in myVar) { resultado.push(myVar[o]) }